# Mongoose findOne to return count of object's sub-array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have data like this:

```
{
  "profileID": "123456789",
  "myArray": [
    {
      "read": false
    },
    {
      "read": true
    },
    {
      "read": false
    },
    {
      "read": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to get the count of: **myArray** where **read** is **false**. I need to do this on Mongoose. In the example above, the return I want is **2**.

My findOne is like below:

```
userModel.findOne({'profileID': 123456789}, function(err, myArray) {
    //Code to run here
});
```

I can manually run through the response and make my count that way but that will be very ineffeciant.

How do I get the count of the user's **myArray's** unread values on the database level?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/):

```
> db.bla.insert({
...   "profileID": "123456789",
...   "myArray": [
...     {
...       "read": false
...     },
...     {
...       "read": true
...     },
...     {
...       "read": false
...     },
...     {
...       "read": true
...     }
...   ]
... })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.bla.aggregate([{$match:{"profileID":"123456789"}}, {$unwind:"$myArray"}, {$match:{"myArray.read":false}}, {$count:"unread_mail"}])
{ "unread_mail" : 2 }
```

You can then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) your array to do your count.

Comment: Works like a charm mate! Initially I had an issue with **$count** but then I looked up the documentation for Mongo that it was introduced in version 3.4 and I was on version 3.2.x So all good after the upgrade. Thanks!